# QGIS 2.14 Python sub-menus

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to add sub-menu items to a menu that linked to a toolbar icon. It's probably best to show what result I'm getting currently, then reference the code:

[image]

The code is coming from a plugin class:

class SandBox2:

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
    self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    self.actions = []

def initGui(self):
    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("Sandbox2")
    self.toolbar.setObjectName("Sandbox2")

    self.SetupSubMenu = QAction((QIcon("C:/Users/Rudy/.qgis2/python/plugins/arcLensStandard/icons/new.png")), "Sub-Item 1-1",self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.submenu_11 = QMenu(self.iface.mainWindow()) 
    self.submenu_11.addAction(self.SetupSubMenu)
    self.SetupSubMenu.triggered.connect(self.runMsg1)

    self.SetupMainMenuItem = QAction((QIcon("C:/Users/Rudy/.qgis2/python/plugins/arcLensStandard/icons/item_one.png")), "First Menu Item", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.Menu1 = QMenu(self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.Menu1.addAction(self.SetupMainMenuItem)
    self.Menu1.addMenu(self.submenu_11)

    self.toolButton = QToolButton()
    self.toolButton.setIcon(QIcon("C:/Users/Rudy/.qgis2/python/plugins/arcLensStandard/icons/adddata.png"))
    self.toolButton.setMenu(self.Menu1)
    self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
    self.toolbar.addWidget(self.toolButton)

def runMsg1(self):
    QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Message", 
        "Sub-Item 1-1 Message", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

What I want to see is the right-facing caret symbol on the same line as the "First Menu Item" string, instead of appearing on a blank line after the string. The statement that's adding the sub-menu is:

```
self.Menu1.addMenu(self.submenu_11)
```

and that's where the blank line gets inserted (apparently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign a name to `Menu1` (e.g. `first_menu`) and then call this when adding your action for your submenu:

```
def initGui(self):
    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("Sandbox2")
    self.toolbar.setObjectName("Sandbox2")

    self.SetupSubMenu = QAction((QIcon("C:/Users/Rudy/.qgis2/python/plugins/arcLensStandard/icons/new.png")), "Sub-Item 1-1",self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.SetupSubMenu.triggered.connect(self.runMsg1)

    self.Menu1 = QMenu(self.iface.mainWindow())
    # Here we assign the name for the first menu
    first_menu = self.Menu1.addMenu(QIcon("C:/Users/Rudy/.qgis2/python/plugins/arcLensStandard/icons/item_one.png"), "First Menu Item")
    # Call first_menu to add the action for the submenu
    first_menu.addAction(self.SetupSubMenu)

    self.toolButton = QToolButton()
    self.toolButton.setIcon(QIcon("C:/Users/Rudy/.qgis2/python/plugins/arcLensStandard/icons/adddata.png"))
    self.toolButton.setMenu(self.Menu1)
    self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
    self.toolbar.addWidget(self.toolButton)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @RudyStricklan - Most welcome, glad it helped =)